# $1,2,...,n(n+1)/2$ placed at random in bottom-heavy nxn triang. array. Prob. that largest num in every row is smaller than largest in any row below?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

From the 1990 Canada National Olympiad:

> $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ distinct numbers are arranged at random into $n$ rows.
>
> The first row has
>   $1$ number, the second has $2$ numbers, the third has $3$ numbers and so on. Find
>   the probability that the largest number in each row is smaller than the largest
>   number in each row with more numbers.

The conclusions I have reached so far:

- it is almost impossible to start from the top of the array, without knowing something about the distribution of numbers below (it is *possible* to meet the conditions for the first row even if it contains a number as large as $n$, whereas it is certain if it contains $1$)
- working from the bottom up, one can see that the last row must contain the number $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ if the condition is to be met

Comment: Your first bullet is wrong.  It is possible if the top number is $\frac {n(n+1)}2-n+1$ because each row could contain the next number and it is far from certain if the top number is $1$.  For $n=3$ you could have the top number be $1$,  then $2,6$ in the next row and $3,4,5$ in the bottom.  Your second bullet is correct.

Comment: I meant just the conditions for the first row. Conditions would still need to be met for all other rows relative to those below them.

Comment: My word wrong is too strong.  I was pointing out that you could have a larger number at the top and still satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Understood. It wasn't wrong, but it was improvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_n$ be the probability that this array meets the desired conditions.  Then we note that for $p_{n+1}$, we need $\frac{(n + 1)(n+2)}{2}$ to be in the last row, and that the first $n$ rows satisfy the desired conditions.  Thus, we have $$p_{n+1} = \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{(n + 1)(n+2)}{2}\text{ is in the last row}\right)p_n.$$

Since the last row has $n+1$ elements, and there are a total of $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$ elements, we have $$ \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{(n + 1)(n+2)}{2}\text{ is in the last row}\right) = \frac{2}{n+2}.$$

We also note that $p_1 = 1$.  Thus, we have \begin{align} p_{n+1} &= \frac{2}{n + 2}p_n \\
&= \frac{2^2}{(n + 2)(n + 1)}p_{n - 1} \\
&= \frac{2^n}{(n+2)(n+1)\cdots 3}\cdot p_1 \\
&= \frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}.
\end{align}

Thus, we have $p_n = \frac{2^n}{(n+1)!}$.  The combinatorialist in me feels like there should be a quick, direct proof of this fact, but I can't come up with one; in the meantime, I think this recursive method works.

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand. When looking at the row above the last one (and so on, inductively), it doesn't really matter what numbers have already been allocated, the only requirement is that you place the largest _remaining_ number in this row. There is always exactly one number that you have to place in each row so that it doesn't cause a violation in some row above.

Comment: Correct, that's precisely it.

Comment: When I enumerate for a 3 tier configuration, I get 40 favorable which gives a probability of  1/18 instead of 1/3 by the formula in both the answers !

Comment: Based on your calculation, it appears that you ordered the rows, since $40 \cdot 18 = 720 = 6!$; the rows should be unordered.  There should be a total of $\binom{6}{3,2,1} = 60$ total possibilities for $n = 3$; this is likely the error in your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_r:=\frac{r(r+1)}{2}$ for every $r=0,1,2,\ldots$.  We are counting the number of ways to arrange the numbers on this triangular array so that the largest number on each row is smaller than that of the next.

On the $n$-th row of the triangular array, the number $T_n$ must be there, and $n-1$ other numbers are chosen from $T_n-1$ numbers.  Hence, there are $n!\cdot \binom{T_n-1}{n-1}$ ways to choose and arrange elements of the $n$-th row.  For $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$, we have $T_{n-k}$ elements left, and the largest of them must be on the $(n-k)$-th row, and $n-k-1$ other entries of this row must be picked from $T_{n-k}-1$ remaining numbers.  Hence, there are $(n-k)!\cdot\binom{T_{n-k}-1}{n-k-1}$ ways to choose and arrange elements for the $(n-k)$-th row.  That is, the number of ways to assign elements into the triangular array according to the rule is 
$$\begin{align}
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\,\left((n-k)!\cdot \binom{T_{n-k}-1}{n-k-1}\right)
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\,\left(\frac{n-k}{T_{n-k}}\cdot\frac{T_{n-k}!}{T_{n-k-1}!}\right)=T_n!\,\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\,\left(\frac{n-k}{T_{n-k}}\right)
\\
&=T_n!\,\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\,\left(\frac{2}{n-k+1}\right)=T_n!\,\left(\frac{2^n}{(n+1)!}\right)\,.
\end{align}$$
Thus, the probability of getting this type of arrangements is $\frac{2^n}{(n+1)!}$.

Comment: When I enumerate for a 3 tier configuration, I get 40 favorable which gives a probability of  1/18 instead of 1/3 by the formula in both the answers !